# Mule Salesforce Query limitations

Tags: salesforce, mule, sfdc-migration-tool

I am trying to understand the Query functionality in Mule Salesforce connector. Can it only return 2000 records max? Does it internally do queryMore? What if I want to extract 100,000 records? Specifically Mule 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are referring to a limitation in Salesforce results rather than in the connector for Mule. Some limits from Salesforce are described here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm